# Can I delete an item using DynamoDB Mapper without loading it first?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am using DynamoDB mapper for deleting an item but have to make sure it exists before deleting it?

So I'm currently doing

```
public void delete(final String hashKey, final Long rangeKey) {
    final Object obj = mapper.load(Object.class, hashKey, rangeKey);
    if (obj != null) {
        mapper.delete(obj);
    } 
}
```

If there a way to delete an item without loading it first? I want it to silently return if the item was not found

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can!

Simply create an object with the ID you want to delete and pass it as an object to the delete method:

```
...
MyObject object = new MyObject();
object.setHashKey(hashKey);
object.setRangeKey(rangeKey);
mapper.delete(object);
....
```

Comment: What happens if the record does not exist in the DDB table?

Comment: The docu says: "nothing happens" : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/IDynamoDBMapper.html#delete-java.lang.Object-

Comment: Why not provide a method to directly delete by hash key? Seems unnecessary to force the client to instantiate a whole new object...

Comment: What is MyObject here?

Comment: It is no more than a POJO with some dynamoDB annotations

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this with `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table` instance:

```
table.deleteItem("hashKeyAttributeName", hashKey, "rangeKeyAttribureName", rangeKey);
```

To create an instance of a Table you can use the following:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAWSAccessKey, amazonAWSSecretKey); // set access and secret keys
AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion("us-west-1") // set aws region
        .build();
Table table = new DynamoDB(amazonDynamoDB).getTable(tableName);
```

Comment: OP's question is about Dynamodb mapper and not midlevel API's

Comment: @Ajak6 what is wrong with answer? I just added one more possibility how to do that using AWS sdk, and it's up to you to decide whether you want to use DynamoDB mapper or not.

Comment: But that's not the question, nothing wrong with your answer though. You can do this using aws cli as well but question is not in how many ways you can delete an item.

Answer (score 0):

Just use DynamoDBTableMapper.deleteifExists
[DynamoDBTableMapper.deleteIfExists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBTableMapper.html#deleteIfExists-T-)